# Using powershell and webhooks

Tags: discord, webhooks

I'm running a gameserver with some mods that contains logs.
What I'm looking for is a script that monitor logfiles, and when a line is added to the file with the word "example", it should output that line to Discord via webhooks.
Also forgot to add that the logs change name on file on each restart.

Is that something that is possible?

I'm all new to this, so I haven't given it a try. Just wanted to know if it is possible or not

example of log:
[image: example of log]

Comment: Please [edit] your post title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of the tag information with the words *Using* and *and* added. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future user of this site who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. The title you've used conveys nothing at all. For some help, see [ask]. You should also read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inotifywait` to monitor the directory for changes, and post an update to the discord webhook using `curl`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Discord webhook token
key=""

# Discord channel ID
channel=""

# Discord username (name the bot will appear as)
username=""

# Replace "example" with the text to look for
inotifywait -m -e create /path/to/log/file | while read line; do

    # Discord message
    message="$line"

    # Send
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"content\":\"$message\",\"username\":\"$username\"}" https://discordapp.com/api/channels/$channel/messages?token=$key
done
```